# Cálculo de dois campos da BD numa função

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel

Boa Tarde, para calcular o orçamento das minhas obras eu utilizo uma query no meu controller ode faz a soma dos campos , sendo poucos registos nao há problema mas caso houver 500, 1000 registos isto torna-se um grande problema no projeto, gostava de fazer uma função em jquery mas está complicado para estes lados.
Obrigado pela sua atenção.

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $services = Service::with('client')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    $budgets=DB::select('SELECT  services.id  , cast(sum(mats.qtd*mats.price+quantityHours*hoursPrice)as decimal (5,2))as BUDGET
                                FROM mats_por_servicos AS mats 
                                INNER JOIN services as services ON mats.serv_id= services.id 
                                group by mats.serv_id, services.id ;');

    return view('services.index',compact('services','budgets'));
}
```

Tabela :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr >

            <th width="20%" class="text-center " scope="col">Cliente</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Morada do Cliente</th>
            <th width="25%" class="text-center" scope="col">Obra</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center" scope="col">Orçamento</th>
            <th width="15%" class="text-center" scope="col">Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($services as $service)
            <?php
                $id = $service->id;
                $prt_budget = 0;
                foreach($budgets as $b )
                {
                    if($b->id == $id )
                    {
                        $prt_budget = $b->BUDGET;
                        break;
                    }
                }?>

                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><a href="/clients/{{$service->client->id}}">{{$service->client->firstName}} {{$service->client->secondName}}</a></td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$service->client->address}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" id="select_serv"><a href="/services/{{$service->id}}">{{$service->designation}}</a></td>
                    <td class="text-center" id="budget">{{$prt_budget}} €</td>{{--tem que listar o orçamento respetivo ao serviço--}}
                    <td class="text-center">{{$service->recordDate}}</td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>`
```

BD model: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi da sua estrutura, você poderia tentar fazer duas coisas:

1 - Na tabela mats_por_servicos, verifique se os campos mat_id e serv_id estão indexados.
2 - Na sua query, você fez um CAST para formatar os valores. Isso é algo que pode impactar no desempenho. Tente retirar o CAST da sua consulta e faça a formatação dos valores no relatório.